# Grammal formal doubt. Context-sensitive grammar

Tags: grammars

In the formal grammar context I am getting confused about the **sensitive-context grammars**.

For this language:

[image: foo+bar]

Looking for it in several sites, I found 2 different **sensitive-context grammars** which can generate it.

**The first one is**:

[image]

where the productions of P are:

[image]

**The second grammar is**

[image]

and the productions of P are:

[image]

Since those should be **sensitive-context grammars**, I understand that the first one is correct, but **not sure if second one is correct too**.

I mean, why those productions:

[image]
[image]

... satisfy the **sensitive-context grammar** restriction? As I understand they dont kept the context.

Can you clarify?.

Comment: Tis is not a research-level question, and as such it is off-topic for this site. It may be more appropriate at https://cs.stackexchange.com . Having said that, the second grammar is not a context-sensitive grammar under the standard definition, but it is a noncontracting grammar, and these are known to generate only context-sensitive languages. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-sensitive_grammar#Formal_definition

Comment: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/52991/5038